# How can I set the session with login use 2 file? Home > login > Home

Tags: php

How can I set the session with login use 2 file? Home > login > Home
did I do something wrong in my code?
Thanks.

home.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>
<?php
    if($_SESSION['account']){
        print"login successful";
        //do something
    }
    else{
        print"login invalid";
        print"
            <form method=\"post\" action=\"login.php\">
                account: <input type=\"text\" name=\"account\"><br>
                password: <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\"><br>
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"login\">
            </form>
        ";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
$account = mysql_escape_string($_POST['account']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
if($account == 'myaccount' && $password == 'mypassword'){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['account'] = $account;
    $_SESSION['password'];
    print"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=home.php\">";
    header("location: home.php");
    exit();
}
else{
    print"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=home.php\">";
    header("location: home.php");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing any data on the `$_SESSION` array.

Try:

```
$_SESSION['account'] = true; // Or something else that evaluates to true and is relevant.
$_SESSION['password'] = 'please, anything but your password plaintext. think of the children';
```

That way, when you test for the result of the login operation on home.php:

```
if($_SESSION['account']){
    print"login successful";
    //do something
}
```

you can satisfy the condition.

Comment: thanks for reply, but after I submit, it will still show invaild (in the else) and I can't understand why?

Comment: Try removing the `print`s in login.php, and leave just the `header()`s. Either way, headers will be sent at the beginning of the response so, unless you are buffering, any call to `header()` after anything has been outputted will be a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your script this :

```
$_SESSION['account'];
$_SESSION['password'];
```

Should be this:

```
$_SESSION['account'] = $account;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

But be aware please do not use this in a production site. this will not work to authenticate users.

You cannot use the session as the only method of logging a person in and keping them logged in. Sessions can easily be hijacked. a good user authentication system will:

encrypt the password

stored user information in the database

collect session information and set it

Now to keep a user logged in, each time they visit a new page you will use the seesion id, the passsword, the user ip, and session variables to authenticate the user and allow them to see the page. Basically you would create a function or a class to handle this in a secure manner.

Now for those that are just starting to learn php, there are a lot of great login scripts already out there. Any good site that Authenticates its users, starts with a really good user authentication system and then builds a site within that.

Answer (score 0):

change line:

```
if($_SESSION['account']){
  print"login successful";
}
```

by

```
if(isset($_SESSION['account']) && $_SESSION['account'] == true){
     print"login successful";
}
```